How to get dynamic rendering in Angular?
Previously, I used to get a build with angular universal as npm run build:ssr. Later, it was requested that each index be accessible separately. I got a build with npm run prerender. Unfortunately, when I get a build like this, google bot can crawl the site as javascript but not as html. How else can I get a build?
